# Setting ForegroundColor in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, foreground

I am writing a User Control in WPF and this on is my first own Control.
For your Information I am using Telerik controls.

My User Control is only a `Grid` which contains only contains 2 `GridView`s.
And now i want to give somebody the possibility to style the `GridView`s by setting a foreground and a background.

Both I set by this way:

```
Background="{Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=DarkBackground}"
Foreground="{Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=LightForeground}"
```

My code behind is:

```
public static DependencyProperty LightForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "LightForeground", typeof( Brush ), typeof( ParameterGrid ) );
public Brush LightForeground
{
  get
  {
    return (Brush)GetValue( LightForegroundProperty );
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue( LightForegroundProperty, value );
  }
}

public Brush DarkBackground
{
  get
  {
    return (Brush)GetValue( DarkBackgroundProperty );
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue( DarkBackgroundProperty, value );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the my foreground, background values are ignored while running.
To set a fix value to the Foreground brings the expected result.

I didn't find my mistake, has anybody an idea???

Comment: Now i know it is a binding issue. Snoop told me:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Grid'. BindingExpression:Path=LightForeground
; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to clarify...you have a `UserControl` with a `Grid` inside and 2 `GridViews`.

To refer to the dependency properties on your UserControl...it can be done in different ways.

### Setting DataContext to Self (code-behind)

In the constructor of your UserControl set the DataContext to point to your UserControl instance.

```
DataContext = this;
```

Then access your properties like so:

```
Background="{Binding DarkBackground}"
Foreground="{Binding LightForeground}"
```

### Setting DataContext to Self (XAML)

If you don't want to do it via code-behind then you can use XAML.

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

### Use a Name on your UserControl and ElementName to refer to it

Put `x:Name="MyUserControl"` on your `UserControl`, and then refer to it with `ElementName`.

```
Background="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=DarkBackground}"
Foreground="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=LightForeground}"
```

---

### Use RelativeSource to tell the Binding the source of the properties.

Specify the "source" of the Binding by using RelativeSource to hunt for the UserControl in the tree.

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DarkBackground}"
Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=LightForeground}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I now using the way with the RelativeSource.